# Создание случайной строки из заданных символов

Tags: java

Имеется строка с символами

```
String symbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Как создать строку со случайной последовательностью этих символов?
Пример выхода:

```
String random = "dsfgfdsfhjdgrdytgfresfdgvc";
```

Comment: 1) разбить на массив посимвольно 2) перемешать 3) склеить | хотя конечно можно сразу перемешивать, при этом для строки использовать `charAt` для взятия символа

Answer (score 3):

Можно так

```
    String symbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    char[] array = symbols.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        arrayList.add(i, String.valueOf(array[i]));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(arrayList);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(arrayList.get(i));
    }
    Log.i("log__", "sb.toString() - " + sb.toString());
```

На выходе

```
I/log__: sb.toString() - jldcgsxkhnfmaqbzuprevwoyti
...
...
```

Чуть по другому, с повторами

```
    String symbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length(); i++) {
        arrayList.add(i, String.valueOf(symbols.charAt(i)));
        Collections.shuffle(arrayList);
        sb.append(arrayList.get(i));
    }
    Log.i("log__", "sb.toString() - " + sb.toString());
```

На выходе

```
I/log__: sb.toString() - aabaebehghilkkhmgrnbiesikp
...
...
```

Вариант №3, тоже с повторами

```
    String symbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    Random random = new Random();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(symbols.charAt(random.nextInt(symbols.length()-1)));
    }
    Log.i("log__", "sb.toString() - " + sb.toString());
```

На выходе

```
I/log__: sb.toString() - bbkigbmmshtgiqctivockuqrkk
...
...
```

Comment: что-то какой-то переизбыток явный

Answer (score 3):

Учитывая, что символы в выводе могут повторяться - нужно лишь сгенерировать последовательность случайных индексов и подставить вместо них символы из исходной строки:

```
String symbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String random = new Random().ints(size, 0, symbols.length())
    .mapToObj(symbols::charAt)
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Длину сгенерированной строки можно менять, задавая нужное значение переменной `size`.