# Необходимо ввести в строку 128 произвольных символов!

Tags: java

Стоит задача проверить, что название может содержать не более 128 символов! Подскажите пожалуйста, как сгенерировать 128 рандомных символов и вставить в строку! язык -java

Comment: Зачем вам генерировать строку из 128 символов, если, судя по условию _"проверить, что название может содержать не более 128 символов"_ вам нужно проверить длину строки?  Или у вас в строке должно быть 128 _уникальных_ символов? Какие символы допускаются в качестве рандомных, цифробуквенные или все подряд?

Comment: Все подряд! Без разницы!

Comment: Соответственно мне нужно ввести в строку 129 символов и получить ошибку!

Comment: Дубликаты по поводу генерации случайных строк: [Создание случайной строки из заданных символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756598/) (2017); [Заполнить массив буквами и цифрами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/217728/)

Comment: То есть как я и предполагал, ваша задача состоит в **проверке длины строки**, которую легко узнать при помощи метода `String::length`.

Comment: Генерация строки из 129 символов `new String(new char[129]).replace("\0", "a");`, [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903603/15035314). Символы одинаковые, но для проверки по длине сгодится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более лаконичный способ для генерации строк из действительно случайных символов, а не только из буквенноцифровых, состоит в использовании метода `Random::nextBytes`, для получения случайного массива байтов:

```java
public static String getRandomStringBytes(int n) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[n];
    new Random().nextBytes(bytes);
    return new String(bytes, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")); 
}
```

Таким способом при необходимости можно получить полную абракадабру, включающую непечатаемые символы, а при использовании многобайтных кодировок типа UTF-8 (`Charset.forName("UTF-8")`) длина строки может оказаться меньше заявленной.

---

Также для получения случайной строки *для известного диапазона символов* можно использовать Stream API, в частности метод [`Random::ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-), и получившийся поток кодовых точек легко преобразовать в строку:

```java
public static String getRandomString(int n, char from, char to) {
    return new Random().ints(n, from, to + 1)
        .collect(() -> new StringBuilder(n), StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

```java
public static String getRandomAlphanum(int n, char from, char to) {
    return new Random().ints(from, to + 1)
        .filter(Character::isLetterOrDigit)
        .limit(n)
        .collect(() -> new StringBuilder(n), StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

Сравнение трёх способов:

```
System.out.println("bytes 128: " + getRandomStringBytes(128));
System.out.println("chars 128: " + getRandomString(128, ' ', 'z'));
System.out.println("alnum 128: " + getRandomAlphanum(128, ' ', 'z'));
```

```
bytes 128: M˜²ÊK ¦ËÏÀ|*ÁXsÎš‘dÆ^2…¾š™÷œ0AB6HhÀf'?Ëí!IYRR+¹ä˜-LMoöþ?)GîÑ‘zÀßü9ãõ¯J1…w+eÂd5ÙÎ±“Zå›Eà˜~ÆöR½Þ
Æ­…9Ö`#‹¬»l&Bš>ffi§
chars 128: 4[]9nuTgXbW6d`X54p];XQY*QjsSB:mdY<N0YAS4%]-l's,5jjYV;\<"$\a"?N;^u&h.M3"'=Vv59_WS7C%@We[GSRl)rm90yi!@44Te9BxN2eFQ[r2DP%;32b`oq7n?
alnum 128: h9P2byiYXzjDSQT9Ac3ODwW8Uu1LimKHHIzvvpwUhE59lNLca7HlSmcoIZGxTqBf7q2p4ufoxKbWqD7wiDwPlEQpuajmk8E9C5EaaOBQH7Zwcljr9ZCUqFlOyjyNEEuN
```

---

Также следует упомянуть, что в библиотеке Apache Commons Lang есть [класс `RandomStringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html), в котором реализовано множество методов для генерации случайных строк нужной длины и формата: `randomAlphabetic`, `randomAlphanumeric`, `randomAscii`, `randomNumeric`, `random`

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать вот такой генератор рандомного String, обычно я использую такой:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateRandomString(128));
    }

    public static String generateRandomString(int length) {
        Random random = new Random();
        String chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            sb.append(chars.charAt(random.nextInt(chars.length())));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Пример результата выполнения: `XUDpqVP5VwfxdPjhW54rhRfIBTKqewVx6lXcrKuhPz2Y9FRF68ibrwR5h837ONsdq5ZKjLDDDTnVpRp7yHO4TInak4VbbEGKLiZI1OS03tI97SB4Cd0wZtLAqAta23Dk`

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @Aleksey Пожалуйста, если ответ Вам помог и больше вопросов нет, нажмите галочку рядом с ответом :)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать цикл for от нуля до 127. В цикле в StringBuilder на каждую итерацию вписывать по символу. Символ это обычный char от 0 до 255, емнип. Соответственно в каждой итерации генерируйте случайную цифру/цисло от 0 до 255, преобразуйте в char и дописывайте в StringBuilder.

Comment: Тип `char` в Java - беззнаковый 16-разрядный для представления Unicode символов, см. [Java Tutorial: Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), считается устаревшим, и часто java-пуритане предлагают использовать вместо него целочисленные (`int`) кодовые точки (code points).

Comment: Огромное мпасибо!!!